# How to detect when all images are loaded and elements are rendered at their appropriate heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loading

How can I check (with **jquery** or **vanilla js**) that all images on a page are loaded, and that they have been rendered at their final, full height, and that their parent elements have adjusted to that height?

I'm implementing a `scrollspy` function using **jquery** - something that determines where a user is on a page and highlights their position in a nav, updating their position as they scroll. In order for this to work properly, I need to know the offset.top of each section on the page I want to spy on. If I calculate the offset.top too early, before all images are loaded and displaying at their full height, the offset().top calculation will be incorrect. I want to avoid running the offset().top calculation too many times.

Things i've tried that don't fulfill my needs:

`$(document).ready() and $(window).onload()` are both too early, as images may not have been rendered at their full height, therefore making the sections not rendered at their full height.

the [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) library. same problem as above, doesn't account for rendering of images to their full height.

Comment: I assume you mean `$(window).on("load"...`

Comment: Are you loading things dynamically or does all the content exist when page is requested from server?

Comment: @epascarello I've been using the [jQuery .load() event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), which I think is interchangeable with what you're saying. forgive my psuedocode as I was writing the original question!

Comment: @epascarello I'm not loading anything dynamically, it's all there with the original request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience I think it's not trivial. `window.onload` may help, but it's not reliable when images are loaded dynamically. In the past I was using some kind of hack to make it workable. Basically, I was using `window.setInterval` and checking if image is really available by looking at property `naturalWidth` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

Here is an example of implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/yu8zr20h/

Answer (score 0):

You are solving this issue in an incorrect way. You need to compare the current Y-value of the users window to the Y-value of all the components, or at least the containers containing the different nav values.

Imagine this is your html-code:

```
<div id="firstContainer">
    <!-- Some content -->
</div>

<div id="secondContainer">
    <!-- Some other content -->
</div>
```

Now you can check the height relative to the complete html page using
`document.gelElementBtId('element-id').offsetTop`

and the current height of the user using
`scrollY`

More information using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbapbcf5/1/).

Comment: I forgot to add that you need to recalculate the offsetTop value each time the checking function is called. So everytime you call the checking function the offsetTop value is the correct one for that moment in time.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm trying to avoid this particular implementation which requires the recalculation of the offsetTop value every time the function is called, for performance reasons. Calculating the offsetTop triggers a repaint of that element(if not the entire page), and I'm already doing other graphics intensive operations while scrolling.

Comment: I did not know that! Could you point me to more information about this?

Comment: [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/#toc-reflowrepaint)  is where I first learned this. Whole article is good but thats a link to this topic.

"Whenever you request the offsetTop property of an element in JavaScript you immediately give the browser a lot of work as it now has to go off and layout the page so it can give you the correct answer. This process is called reflowing. If we then change another property of the element based on the offsetTop value the element (and consequently its compositor layer) will need to be repainted, which may be expensive."

Comment: In my previous comment i meant "reflow" and not "repaint".

Answer (score 0):

If you have image size metadata (e.g. Rails Active Storage provide it out of the box), you can write height to say dataset:

```
 <img id="image" data-height="700" src="image.jpg" />
```

Then wait for it to be rendered (watch natural height):

```
let timer;
let image = document.getElementById("image");
function waitImage() {
    if (image.naturalHeight < image.dataset.height) {
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            showItems();
        }, 300);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);

        useYourFullyRenderedImage();
    }
}
```